# assigning palette to elements in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, colors

I'm using code to generate a Swimmer's plot, but running into customization difficulty. with 3 staging categories, the colors are too similar. How can I set a palette in aes, but have consistent element lengths?

[image: swimmer's plot - teal on teal]

Tried this instead of colour=variable: colorRampPalette(c("blue","red"))((length(dat$Subject)))

```
set.seed(33)
dat = data.frame(Subject = 1:10, 
                 Months = sample(4:20, 10, replace=TRUE),
                 Treated=sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE),
                 Stage = sample(1:3, 10, replace=TRUE),
                 Continued=sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE))

dat = dat %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  mutate(Complete=sample(c(4:(max(Months)-1),NA), 1, 
                         prob=c(rep(1, length(4:(max(Months)-1))),5), replace=TRUE),
         Partial=sample(c(4:(max(Months)-1),NA), 1, 
                        prob=c(rep(1, length(4:(max(Months)-1))),5), replace=TRUE),
         Durable=sample(c(-0.5,NA), 1, replace=TRUE))

# Order Subjects by Months
dat$Subject = factor(dat$Subject, levels=dat$Subject[order(dat$Months)])

# Melt part of data frame for adding points to bars
dat.m = melt(dat %>% select(Subject, Months, Complete, Partial),
             id.var=c("Subject","Months"))

ggplot(dat, aes(Subject, Months)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=factor(Stage)), width=0.7) +
  geom_point(data=dat.m, 
             aes(Subject, value, colour=variable, shape=variable), size=4) +
  geom_segment(data=dat %>% filter(Continued==1), 
               aes(x=Subject, xend=Subject, y=Months + 0.1, yend=Months + 1), 
               pch=15, size=0.8, arrow=arrow(type="closed", length=unit(0.1,"in"))) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=hcl(seq(15,375,length.out=5)[1:4],100,70)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(hcl(seq(15,375,length.out=3)[1:2],100,40),"black")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,20), breaks=0:20) +
  labs(fill="Disease Stage", colour="", shape="", 
       x="Subject Recevied Study Drug") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

Comment: I had a look and the colors are not similar at all - a bit grating maybe, but not similar. So I don't know what your problem really is. Can you be more specific, maybe post an image?

Comment: Also as far as I can tell the `pch=15` does not do anything except cause a shape warning. And you could add an `na.rm=T` parameter to your `geom_point` call to avoid the NA removal warnings.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I've got teal on teal. Please see the screenshot above.

Comment: So you mean the dark teal triangle on the light teal bar? They are quite easily distinguishable on my screen.

Comment: what is wrong with something like this: `scale_colour_manual(values=c("darkblue","darkred"))`

Comment: Screen yes - blowing it up on a poster is not ideal. With that I get:"Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: shape
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (14): x, y, colour, shape
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the following modifications:

- got rid of the `pch=` parameter in `geom_segment` call, as it is not a geom_segment parameter.
- changed the `set_colour_manual` call to set two colors explicitly as `darkblue` and `darkred`. These control the color of the symbols
- added a `na.rm=T`parameter the `geom_point` call to suppress missing value warnings that were being emitted..

The resulting code looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
set.seed(33)
dat = data.frame(Subject = 1:10, 
                 Months = sample(4:20, 10, replace=TRUE),
                 Treated=sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE),
                 Stage = sample(1:3, 10, replace=TRUE),
                 Continued=sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE))

dat = dat %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  mutate(Complete=sample(c(4:(max(Months)-1),NA), 1, 
                         prob=c(rep(1, length(4:(max(Months)-1))),5), replace=TRUE),
         Partial=sample(c(4:(max(Months)-1),NA), 1, 
                        prob=c(rep(1, length(4:(max(Months)-1))),5), replace=TRUE),
         Durable=sample(c(-0.5,NA), 1, replace=TRUE))

# Order Subjects by Months
dat$Subject = factor(dat$Subject, levels=dat$Subject[order(dat$Months)])

# Melt part of data frame for adding points to bars
dat.m = melt(dat %>% select(Subject, Months, Complete, Partial),
             id.var=c("Subject","Months"))

ggplot(dat, aes(Subject, Months)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=factor(Stage)), width=0.7) +
  geom_point(data=dat.m, na.rm=T,
             aes(Subject, value, colour=variable, shape=variable), size=4) +
  geom_segment(data=dat %>% filter(Continued==1), 
               aes(x=Subject, xend=Subject, y=Months + 0.1, yend=Months + 1), 
               size=0.8, arrow=arrow(type="closed", length=unit(0.1,"in"))) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=hcl(seq(15,375,length.out=5)[1:4],100,70)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("darkblue","darkred")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,20), breaks=0:20) +
  labs(fill="Disease Stage", colour="", shape="", 
       x="Subject Recevied Study Drug") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

This creates the following plot on `ggplot` 2.2.1 with no warnings.

[image]

Of course I didn't see all the warnings you mentioned, so maybe check the versions. Here is my `sessionInfo()`.

[image]

Comment: Error was from misuse of the color scaling. Thanks that looks much better. To improve grouping though, I'd like to order them by stage in descending number of months with a slightly larger gap between these stage groups. What's the best way of assigning these levels?        dat$Subject[order(dat$Stage[order(dat$Months,decreasing = TRUE)])])

Comment: Using `dat$Subject = factor(dat$Subject, levels=dat$Subject[order(dat$Months,decreasing = T)])` reverses the order nicely, inverting the plot from top to bottom. And you can vary the width of the bars by playing with the `width=0.7` value.

Comment: Also, there are 2 pieces to the legend - the stage and the CR/PR. When I use legend.position = c(0.9, 1.1), I lose the stage piece. I tried to add position=c(0.9,0.8) to the labs(fill="Disease Stage", colour="", shape="", x="Subject Recevied Study Drug")

Comment: Labels are fragile things, one of the main issues with `ggplot`, although it does them much better than most packages. Experimentation is the only way forward, but you can spend a lot of time there.